# Responsive issue - 3 column layout

Tags: html, css

I have been working on making a site responsive for a client. The client wants the left menu to drop to the bottom when the site collapses down. All pages work this way and here is an example:

[Page working correctly](http://dev.icsandbox.com/about-us/overview/)

However, there is one page that is 3 columns (all others are two columns) that isn't working properly and here is the example:

[Not working correctly](http://dev.icsandbox.com/about-us/senior-professionals/james-g-b-demartini/)

Right now the structure of the page not working correctly is:

```
<div class="content-column-left" id="bio-nav"></div>
<div class="content-column-center"></div>
<div class="content-column-right"></div>
```

I have noted that if I rearrange the columns in Developer tools so they sit like this:

```
<div class="content-column-center"></div>
<div class="content-column-right"></div>
<div class="content-column-left" id="bio-nav"></div>
```

I can then add a float:left and a width=21% to the #bio-nav and then a float:right to the other two divs and I get what I want on collapse, but it looks terrible at full screen.

How do I make this work so that that column with the navigation collapses to the bottom like the other pages? I am willing to restructure things as needed. Thanks!

EDIT: I made a small change to the structure and adjusted so the widths are percentages. At this point the right column refuses to collapse under the center column at all: [Updated way site is collapsing](http://dev.icsandbox.com/about-us/senior-professionals/james-g-b-demartini/)

Answer (score 0):

On that page the markup needs to be as follows:

```
<div class="content-column-right content-body content-right-team-member"></div>
<div class="content-column-center content-body content-body-team-member"></div>
<div class="content-column-left" id="bio-nav></div>

Then
    .content-column-right
needs to be 
    float:right

Then
    .content-column-center
needs to be
    float:right

Then (I think this one is okay as is)
    .content-column-left
needs to be:
    float: left
```

Anything after that your just going to have to mess with it

Comment: This mostly works, but when collapsing, column right winds up above column center.

Comment: Get the columns to shift that way will be a pain. Basically your going to have to do a lot of customizations to get it to work correctly. Tweak somethng and test.

Comment: Have a look now. I managed to get them in the right order, but the right area doesn't ever drop below the center area. It just shrinks and shrinks. Any ideas? http://dev.icsandbox.com/about-us/senior-professionals/james-g-b-demartini/